# Iterate through jagged array

Tags: powershell, scripting, jagged-arrays

I'm learning Powershell Scripting and right now I'm trying to iterate through an array consisting of 2 value arrays while only printing out the first value.

For example, take the below array;

```
$array = (("fizz", "buzz"),
          ("foo", "bar"))
```

I would like to be able to print out the first values, so `fizz` and `buzz`.

Right now, I have the following code;

```
Foreach ($a in $array)
{
    Write-Host $a[0]
}
```

What I should be getting is `fizz`, but instead I'm getting `fizz buzz [0]`

Thanks

Comment: The symptom you describe is inconsistent with the code in the question, which works as expected. It sounds like the actual code that produced your symptom is `Write-Host "$a[0]"`, i.e., a mistaken application of string expansion (interpolation); to reference _expressions_ such as `$a[0]` inside `"..."`, you must use `$(...)`: `"$($a[0])"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think of the multidimensional array as a table with rows and columns like so:

[image]

so in your example where you want to get the first two columns in the first row, what you want is

```
$array[0][0]
$array[0][1]
```

You can check this by running:

```
Write-Host $array[0][0]
Write-Host $array[0][1]
```

What you are doing is iterating through each row and printing out column 0 for each row.

```
Foreach ($a in $array)
{
    Write-Host $a[0]
}
```

This is saying foreach row in $array print out column 0. To get your code working as expected you would need to change `$array` to `$array[0]`:

```
Foreach ($a in $array[0])
{
    Write-Host $a
}
```

This will give you the expected results and reads as foreach column in row 0 print column. The loop is however unnecessary as you can get the same result by simply using:

```
Write-Host $array[0]
```

Which just prints out the entire row.

Answer (score 0):

you can address the individual array items with one index per dimension. with your sample array, the following would give the 1st item of each axis ...

```
'{0}; {1}' -f $array[0][0], $array[1][0]
```

output ...

```
fizz; foo
```